# Efficiency of retrieving Eigen block versus entry in std::vector

Tags: c++, eigen, stdvector, eigen3

I am unclear as to how Eigen's blocks are compiled, which may be relevant e.g. in for-loops.
As a specific example, **what would be the difference between**

```
Eigen::VectorXd x(3*N);
Eigen::VectorXd y(3*N);
Eigen::VectorXd z(N);
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    z[i] = x.block<3,1>(3*i).dot(y.block<3,1>(3*i));
}
```

and

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> x(N);
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> y(N);
std::vector<double>          z(N);
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    z[i] = x[i].dot(y[i]);
}
```

Would the first create references to the various blocks at each iteration or would it be compiled down to roughly the same as a vector element access?

Comment: Both code should boils down to equivalent asm, but of course we cannot predict compiler job with 100% accuracy, so the only way to be sure is to look at the generated assembly for your compiler (don't forget compiler optimization like -O3)